# How Can I remove space between widgets in flutter

Tags: flutter, widget

Hello How can I remove this space between the logo and the Text "Privacy Policy"
Below is my code and space position.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are images background opaque?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that reducing the height of the container you place the image in should help solve the problem.